# How to fold vector of vector in rust?

Tags: rust, fold

I have a vector of vector like the following.

```
    let m: Vec<Vec<u64>> = vec![
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ];
```

And `add` function that is intended add each element of two vector.

```
fn add(xs: &Vec<u64>, ys: &Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    xs.iter().zip(ys.iter()).map(|(x, y)| x + y).collect()
}
```

Now, I want to `fold` the vector of vector `m`.

What I tried is:

```
    let s: Vec<u64> = m[1..]
        .iter()
        .fold(m[0], |acc, xs| add(&acc, xs));
```

But this code doesn't pass the compiler.

```
   |
16 |         .fold(m[0], |acc, xs| add(&acc, xs));
   |               ^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Vec<u64>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I tried prepend `&` but the compiler still rejects:

```
   |
16 |         .fold(&m[0], |acc, xs| add(&acc, xs));
   |               ^^^^^ expected struct `Vec`, found `&Vec<u64>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<u64>`
           found reference `&Vec<u64>`
help: consider removing the borrow
   |
16 -         .fold(&m[0], |acc, xs| add(&acc, xs));
16 +         .fold(m[0], |acc, xs| add(&acc, xs));
   |
```

I think the signature of `add` function is correct as it doesn't want to take ownership of the arguments vectors, and it returns a new vector so the ownership should be passed to the caller.

Actually, I tried every possible combinations (add/remove `&` from the function, etc.), but couldn't make the code pass the compiler.

Can you let me know what I missed, what is wrong with the above code? Thanks.

Comment: The first argument of `fold` must be the same type as its output. Therefore passing `& m[0]`, which has type `& Vec<u64>`, won't work, since you want the fold to return `Vec<u64>`. One option could be to start with `m[0].clone()` as the initial value. That does involve a cloning, obviously, but you need to allocate your output somehow anyway.

Comment: Note: I only this is an old question, but for posterity, `&Vec<T>` is an antipattern: use `&[T]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `fold` must be the same type as its output. Therefore your suggestion of passing `& m[0]`, which has type `& Vec<u64>`, won't work, since you want the fold to return `Vec<u64>` (notice value vs borrowed value). And using `m[0]` (without borrowing) won't work because you would be trying to move from a vector that is later used (in the iteration itself).

One option could be to start with `m[0].clone()` as the initial value. That does involve a cloning, obviously, but you need to allocate your output somehow anyway, so you can't do better. This works:

```
let s: Vec<u64> = m[1..].iter().fold(m[0].clone(), |acc, xs| add(& acc, xs));
```

---

Unrelatedly: I suggest you change `add` to have the more general signature `fn add(xs: & [u64], ys: & [u64]) -> Vec<u64>`. You can still use it the way you are (because `& Vec<u64>` coerces into `& [u64]`), but it's more general, because other types coerce into `& [u64]` too.

Comment: You mentioned adding `clone()` is the one option. Can you explain the other possible options, please?

Comment: @ntalbs: Good question! Actually, I don't see any better options. The result vector needs to be allocated at some point. The only other reasonable option seems to me to be to set the initial value to a vector of zeros, and then fold over all of `m`, but that's not better than just initializing with a clone of `m[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```rust
let first = m.pop().unwrap();
let s: Vec<u64> = m
        .iter()
        .fold(first, |acc, xs| add(&acc, xs));
```

this avoids cloning the first argument. It assumes that the order of the operation does not matter.

Comment: And changes the original `m`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this answer isn't valid: in the phrasing of the question, `m` is immutable, so you may not do `m.pop()`.

Comment: The question is not phrased as assuming `m` is immutable - it is phrased as having full ownership of `m`, which implies that mutating it is an option.